# red border around text field when validation fails

Tags: javascript, css, validation

I'm trying to put a red border and possible a background color on my text fields on my contact form when the validations fails. So far I got this, but nothing is happening?

JS SCRIPT:

```
<script>

function checkforblank() {

    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('fornavn').value == "") {
        errormessage += "skriv dit fornavn \n";
        document.getElementById('fornavn').style.borderColor = "red";

    if (document.getElementById('efternavn').value == "") {
        errormessage += "skriv dit fornavn \n";
        document.getElementById('efternavn').style.borderColor = "red";

    if (errormessage != "") {
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

FORM CODE: (the form is much longer, this is just the part i'm testing)

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input3">
    <input type="text" id="fornavn" class="detail3" name="fornavn" onsubmit="return checkforblank()" placeholder="Fornavn*" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fornavn'])? $_POST['fornavn'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('fornavn',    $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fornavn']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- slut .input -->

    <div class="input3">
    <input type="text" id="efternavn" class="detail3" name="efternavn" placeholder="Efternavn*" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['efternavn'])? $_POST['efternavn'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('efternavn',    $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['efternavn']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- slut .input -->

    </div><!-- slut .row -->
```

PHP VALIDATION:

```
<?php


function validate_email_address($email = false) {
return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? true : false;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = false) {
return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'mail@sverkel.dk';
$email_subject = 'Formular: Kontakt os';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fornavn', 'efternavn', 'vejnavn', 'nr', 'postnr', 'by', 'email', 'mobil', 'fastnet', 'besked');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
'fornavn' => 'Skriv dit fornavn',
'efternavn' => 'Skriv dit efternavn',
'vejnavn' => 'Skriv dit vejnavn',
'nr' => 'Fejl',
'postnr' => 'Skriv post nr.',
'by' => 'Skriv bynavn',
'email' => 'Skriv e-mail adresse',
'mobil' => 'Skriv mobilnummer',
'fastnet' => 'Skriv fastnetnummer',
'besked' => 'Skriv en besked'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// boolean variable to validate recaptcha
$valid_recaptcha = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// First validate recaptcha

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey = "6LfEZw0TAAAAAOkn4MM4DfsMjmYoG0WetmhuLzmQ";
$response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data = json_decode($response);
if($data->success) {
    $valid_recaptcha = true;
}

if($valid_recaptcha){

    // now process your form here. sanitize and validate input fields

    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));
    }

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       

        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)){
            array_push($validation, $field);
        }

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == ''){
            array_push($validation, $field);
        }

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email'){
            if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])){
                array_push($validation, $field);
            }
        }

    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {

        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'Ny besked fra kontaktformular: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if($key != 'submit' && $key != 'g-recaptcha-response') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n\n";

        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;

    }

 }
}


?>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#formWrap {
width:560px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid #FF0004;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-moz-box-shadow:2px #DFDFDF;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px #DFDFDF;
padding:16px 10px 10px;
}

#formWrap #form {
border-top:1px solid #EEE;
width:560px;
}

#form .row {
border-bottom:1px solid #EEE;
display:block;
line-height:38px;
overflow:auto;
padding: 14px 0px;
width:100%;
}

#form .row .label {
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:120px;
text-align:right;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#form .row .input {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

#form .row .input2 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:25px;
width:50px;
}

#form .row .input3 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

#form .row .input4 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

#form .row .input5 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

#form .row .input6 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

#form .row .input7 {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
}

.detail {
width:252px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail2 {
width:47px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail3 {
width:252px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail4 {
width:531px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail5 {
width:232px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail6 {
width:100px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.detail7 {
width:403px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.mess {
width:531px;
max-width:531px;
height:200px;
overflow:auto;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
padding:7px 8px;
line-height:1em;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background:#EDEDED;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.recaptcha {
color:#FF0004;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
background-image:url(../images/x.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left 6px;
padding-left:30px;
margin-left: 200px;

}

.detail:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail2:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail3:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail4:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail5:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail6:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.detail7:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

.mess:focus{
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #999;
outline:none;
}

#form .row .context {
color:#999; 
font-size:11px;
font-style:italic;
line-height:40px;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
width:200px;
float:left;
}

#form #submit {
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
margin-top:25px;
margin-left:0px;
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
padding:10px;
}

span.error {
color:#FF0004;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
background-image:url(../images/x.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left 6px;
padding-left:30px;

}

#formWrap h3 {
font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-left:-1px;
}

#formWrap h6 {
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: italic;
margin-left:-1px;
}

input.error {
border:1px solid #FF0004;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width:120px;
text-align:right;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

---

PROVIDED CODE: NEW!

```
<script>

function checkForBlank() {

    var form = document.getElementById('comments_form');

        for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {

        if(form.elements[i].type != 'submit') {

        if(form.elements[i].value == '') {
            form.elements[i].style.borderColor = 'red';
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

FORM CODE:

```
 <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input3">
    <input type="text" id="fornavn" class="detail3" name="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn*" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fornavn'])? $_POST['fornavn'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('fornavn',    $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fornavn']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- slut .input -->

    <div class="input3">
    <input type="text" id="efternavn" class="detail3" name="efternavn" placeholder="Efternavn*" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['efternavn'])? $_POST['efternavn'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('efternavn',    $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['efternavn']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- slut .input -->

    </div><!-- slut .row -->
```

SUBMIT CODE:

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkForBlank()" value="Send besked" />
    </div><!-- .submit -->
```

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean? The script is supposed to check the form if it is empty?

Comment: @peter, Jquery for such a simple thing?
My claxon of my car just broke, should i buy a new car?

Comment: @RFLdev If that car is free, like jQuery, why not. - To the point. I know it's a bit overkill but it can help, not just with this issue but with all code.

Comment: Sorry for missing the point. Just added the PHP validation to the post.

Comment: You need to add } after the if statements. AND onsubmit is for a form, not for inputs

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put } after the if statements.
And onsubmit is for the form not for the inputs.
This without the php part should work:

```
   <form onsubmit="checkforblank()">
<input type="text" id="fornavn" class="detail3" name="fornavn" onsubmit="return checkforblank()" placeholder="Fornavn*" value="">


    <input type="text" id="efternavn" class="detail3" name="efternavn" placeholder="Efternavn*" value="">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

<script>
function checkforblank() {

    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('fornavn').value == "") {
        errormessage += "skriv dit fornavn \n";
        var input = document.getElementById('fornavn').style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('efternavn').value == "") {
        errormessage += "skriv dit fornavn \n";
        document.getElementById('efternavn').style.borderColor = "red";
}

    if (errormessage != "") {
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Got it! Can someone give me an advice on how to do both validations? I like the text under the textfield and the little icon?

Comment: You can make an array where you keep all the inputs, and loop over it. it reduces the amount of code,and it will check all fields for empty in one loop.

Comment: ehm okay... You lost me there :D Must I ask for your help or some links to guides on how to do that?

Comment: Here is a quick example, pls note, its far from complete, and just to give you an idea. http://jsfiddle.net/y0y9ko29/

Comment: Thank you for the code, but for some reason I can't get it to work? I have updated the post with the new code.

Comment: That is the old code. Please look from where it says "PROVIDED CODE:" Thats what is in there now.

I can see for 1 sec. that the red borders gå around all my fields, but then my other validation kicks in and removes the red border?

I would really like for them both to be there? Will it be easier using jQuery?

Comment: @bignoob What other validation? You can loop through the elements and set your own validation in the same loop! its like if(elements[i].name = 'dummy') { // do your validation }

it can all be done in the same loop, no need for extra validation functions...

Comment: To start with I got validation og the form and input fields, then I got validation on the reCaptcha and now I want the effect with the red border, but my first validation is breaking the last with the red border. I only understand a little what you are telling me, but I would think that if I did the validation with the red border and drop my first validation, is there still a way to place the text under the input instead of in a pop up box?

Comment: Sure, just make a span, or a div. and fill it with document.getElementById('placeToPutError').innerHTML = 'Error, please check input!';

But javascript can be disabled or manipulated, so you also need to check the vars serverside, to be sure you dont get any false data.